# Rails 4 - Proper method to display attributes from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning rails 4 and i'd like to know how to display in a show action an attribute coming from another model.

For information, a Deal belongs_to a business_line and a business_line has many deals.

Here is the show action for the deal controller. I'd like to display the name of the linked business_line (instead of the ID, which is stored in the Deal table) :

```
<div class = 'container'>
<h1> <%= @deal.name %> </h1>
<p> <%= @deal.bank_id %> </p>
<p> <%= business_line.name %> </p>

<%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_deal_path %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', deal_path(@deal), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
</div>
```

Here is my Deal controller :

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_deal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def show
        @deal.business_line_id = @business_line.id
    end
private

    def deals_params
        params.require(:deal).permit(:name, :bank_id, :business_line_id)
    end

    def find_deal
        @deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

What do i have to put into my Deal controller to be able to call the business_line.name in my Deal view?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `@deal.business_line.name` since you already associated the models.

Just a question, why are you doing this in the show action? Where was `@business_line` initialized?

Comment: @Etienne This will work as long as you have set up your Deal model and BusinessLine model with the has_many and belongs_to relationships that you referenced

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked :). By the way, if i wanted to be compliant with the law of Demeter, what would i need to do?